# How to add Action bar options menu in Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to have a options menu in **Android Fragments**. `ActionBar` options menu are not displaying in my Fragments.

Here is my code and I have both `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and `onOptionSelected()` function. My code doesn't shows any error. But options menu are not displaying.

```
package org.reachout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import org.general.R;

public class ViewMessageFragment extends Fragment {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container == null) {
            // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
            // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist.  The fragment
            // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
            // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
            // won't be displayed.  Note this is not needed -- we could
            // just run the code below, where we would create and return
            // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
            return null;
        }
        return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewmessages_tab_fragment_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.askexperts_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // handle item selection
       switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.action_settings:
             // do s.th.
             return true;
          default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
       }
    }   

}
```

Comment: It worked for me, I was using        setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreateView instead of onCreate. calling        setHasOptionsMenu(true); from onCreate solved my problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the activity that is associated with fragment?
I mean that no code has to be written in the activity for showing the menu.
Just the fragment has to attached to the activity.
Please reply asap.

Answer (score 94):

You need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in `onCreate()`.

For backwards compatibility it's better to place this call as late as possible at the end of `onCreate()` or even later in `onActivityCreated()` or something like that.

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)

Comment: thanks. But i have got this working in Android 4.0+. But not on my Android Gingerbread 2.3.3 version and above for some reason. I have updated my code above. Please help me to get this fixed in Android 2.3.3 and above also.

Comment: Move the `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` at the end of `onCreateView()`. Like `View v = inflater.inflate(); setHasOptionsMenu(true); return v;`

Comment: I have tried as you said. But still its not display in Android Gingerbread.

Comment: It didn't work for me either with ABS on 4.4. Instead, I went a different route. My fragments were in a FragmentPagerAdapter, and I just added and removed a menu item dynamically in onPageSelected().

Comment: I have added setHasOptionMenu(true) in onCreate method of the fragment. Also have inflated menu as explain in the question. But i got option menu when user click on the Menu button. I would like to have it in the ActionBar with in the fragment. So how to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It work like a charm, regardless where I place it: at the end of onCreateView() or at the end of onActivityCreated().

Comment: If you see Gmail app in Tablet, it has list Menu items placed just above the list and message view menu items at right corner. How to achieve that functionality?

Comment: @iDroidExplorer set 'app:showAsAction="always" in your menu item

Answer (score 89):

> I am late for the answer but I think this is another solution which is
>   not mentioned here so posting.

**Step 1:** Make a xml of menu which you want to add like I have to add a filter action on my action bar so I have created a xml **filter.xml**. The main line to notice is **android:orderInCategory** this will show the action icon at first or last wherever you want to show. One more thing to note down is the value, if the value is less then it will show at first and if value is greater then it will show at last.

**filter.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:icon="@drawable/filter"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


</menu>
```

**Step 2:** In **onCreate()** method of fragment just put the below line as mentioned, which is responsible for calling back **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)** method just like in an **Activity**.

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
```

**Step 3:** Now add the method **onCreateOptionsMenu** which will be override as:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.filter, menu);  // Use filter.xml from step 1
    }
```

**Step 4:** Now add **onOptionsItemSelected** method by which you can implement logic whatever you want to do when you select the added action icon from **actionBar**:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_filter){
            //Do whatever you want to do 
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean in Step 3 to inflate `filter.xml`? Where did `R.menu.search_result` come from?

Comment: Yes its `filter.xml`. Changed the name of xml in step 3.

Comment: Thought as much but didn't want to edit your answer without clarifying as I'm still slowly working my way through my own issues. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score -18):

in AndroidManifest.xml set theme holo like this:

```
<activity
android:name="your Fragment or activity"
android:label="@string/xxxxxx"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
```

Comment: How exactly would that have helped?