# Different Action Button in Action Bar for Different Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am implementing Custom Action Bar in my App. In a fragment i am also using Tab Navigation. For that i have a Parent Fragment in which i make web requests and five other fragments for Tab Navigation. I want to add different Action Button in Action Bar for Different Fragmnet and their listener accordingly. I have only one Activity which is inflating my custom Action Bar.

Here is the Code for My Activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListLeft;
    private ListView mDrawerListRight;

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItemsLeft;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItemsRight;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapterLeftDrawer;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapterRightDrawer;

    public static ActionBar myCustomActionBar;

    ImageButton imgLeftMenu;
    ImageButton imgRightMenu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#93b636")));

        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));

        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v);

        myCustomActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for My Frgment Listner

```
public class Shops extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = new String[] {"Tab 1", "Tab 2", "Tab 3", "Tab 4"};
    public Shops(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shop, container, false);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = MainActivity.myCustomActionBar;
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());        
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

And This is My Tab Fragment

```
public class ShopFragment extends Fragment {
    public ShopFragment(){}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_button, menu);
    }
}
```

My sort Button XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_sort"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/Shops">
    </item>

</menu>
```

Any Help or Useful tutorial will be Appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which Actionbar are you using ? i.e, **Sherlock ActionBar** or **Compat Actionbar** ?

Comment: I am Using Compat Actionbar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()` of your fragment. This will allow you to set different option menus on fragments. Setup your options menu from within `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)`

Moreover, To get your Action bar instance, write `getSuppportActionBar()` and then make whatever changes you want to do.

For backwards compatibility it's better to place this call as late as possible at the end of `onCreate()` or even later in `onActivityCreated()` or something like that.

See [this for more info.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean))

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks For Help. Actually i have created a layout and inflate that in my Action Bar. i already Called **setHasOptionsMenu(true);** and Got Reference to ActionBar Using **getSuppportActionBar()**. Now I am confused what to Do Next. Should i inflate another layout..? I am not using Menu.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to Change the title of action bar on different fragments ?

Comment: Actually i want to add button to Sort the list view in different order only for 2 fragments.

Comment: Then create 1 menu.xml with the button you want and inflate that inside `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` on those 2 fragments.

Comment: Make sure you override `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)` only on those fragments where you want changes in actionbar menu.

Comment: I am going to work on your suggestion. I have Added some Code as well please have a look.

Comment: Add `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate()` method of your fragment.

Comment: It added Overflow icon

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/edit_item"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_sort"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/Shops">
    </item>

</menu>`

Comment: `@Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.sort_button, menu);
 }`

Comment: Ok.Is the icon getting displayed on your fragment's actionbar ?

Comment: No. Only title is showing, when i click the overflow icon

Comment: I am actually not getting what you are trying to say. please update your code here with your current code and then tell me what is going wrong.

Comment: I have updated my code. Because of reputation can't be able to Add images

Comment: You can upload the image on dropbox and share the link here.

Comment: I want Some thing like that https://www.dropbox.com/s/7qwacxx0ol5nc3f/Screenshot_2014-07-07-12-03-17.png

Comment: After your suggested modification i got this https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6p45wn7irstahc/Screenshot_2014-07-07-12-03-21.png

Comment: Try changing `android:orderInCategory="100"` and android:showAsAction="always" in menu.xml

Comment: Getting Same behaviour

Comment: see [this might help you out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714322/how-to-add-action-bar-options-menu-in-android-fragments) and [this also](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-action-items-from-within-fragments/)