# Clear all list item on button click

Tags: android

I have created simple chatting application and it contains some `ListView` which handles all chat messages, but every `ListView` is defined in another class. I want to clear my list items from *Clear Chat* from an overflow menu, which is present in main activity. How can I achieve this?

Here is my main activity called `WiFiServiceDiscoveryActivity`:

```
public class WiFiServiceDiscoveryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    DeviceClickListener, Handler.Callback, MessageTarget,
    ConnectionInfoListener {
    public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";
    // TXT RECORD properties
    public static final String TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE = "available";
    public static final String SERVICE_INSTANCE = " ";
    public static final String SERVICE_REG_TYPE = "_presence._tcp";
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 0x400 + 1;
    public static final int MY_HANDLE = 0x400 + 2;
    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    static final int SERVER_PORT = 4545;
    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    private Channel channel;
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;
    private WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest serviceRequest;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(this);
    private WiFiChatFragment chatFragment;
    private WiFiDirectServicesList servicesList;
    private TextView statusTxtView;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private String friend;


    private WiFiP2pService service;
    WiFiChatFragment listView;
    WiFiChatFragment.ChatMessageAdapter a;



    public Handler getHandler() {
        return handler;
    }
    public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
        this.handler = handler;
    }
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


        statusTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter
                .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        intentFilter
                .addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        manager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        channel = manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);
        startRegistrationAndDiscovery();
        servicesList = new WiFiDirectServicesList();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container_root, servicesList, "services").commit();

            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("services");
        if (frag != null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();
        }
        super.onRestart();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (manager != null && channel != null) {
            manager.removeGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                }
            });
        }
        super.onStop();
    }
    /**
     * Registers a local service and then initiates a service discovery
     */
    private void startRegistrationAndDiscovery() {
        Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<String, String>();
        record.put(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE, "visible");
        WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo service = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceInfo.newInstance(
                SERVICE_INSTANCE, SERVICE_REG_TYPE, record);
        manager.addLocalService(channel, service, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //appendStatus("Added Local Service");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int error) {
                // appendStatus("Failed to add a service");
            }
        });
        discoverService();
    }
    private void discoverService() {
        /*
         * Register listeners for DNS-SD services. These are callbacks invoked
         * by the system when a service is actually discovered.
         */
        manager.setDnsSdResponseListeners(channel,
                new DnsSdServiceResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDnsSdServiceAvailable(String instanceName,
                                                        String registrationType, WifiP2pDevice srcDevice) {
                        // A service has been discovered. Is this our app?
                        if (instanceName.equalsIgnoreCase(SERVICE_INSTANCE)) {
                            // update the UI and add the item the discovered
                            // device.
                            WiFiDirectServicesList fragment = (WiFiDirectServicesList) getFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentByTag("services");
                            if (fragment != null) {
                                WiFiDevicesAdapter adapter = ((WiFiDevicesAdapter) fragment
                                        .getListAdapter());
                                 service = new WiFiP2pService();
                                service.device = srcDevice;
                                service.instanceName = instanceName;
                                service.serviceRegistrationType = registrationType;
                                adapter.add(service);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Log.d(TAG, "onBonjourServiceAvailable "
                                        + instanceName);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new DnsSdTxtRecordListener() {
                    /**
                     * A new TXT record is available. Pick up the advertised
                     * buddy name.
                     */
                    @Override
                    public void onDnsSdTxtRecordAvailable(
                            String fullDomainName, Map<String, String> record,
                            WifiP2pDevice device) {
                        Log.d(TAG,
                                device.deviceName + " is "
                                        + record.get(TXTRECORD_PROP_AVAILABLE));
                    }
                });
        // After attaching listeners, create a service request and initiate
        // discovery.
        serviceRequest = WifiP2pDnsSdServiceRequest.newInstance();
        manager.addServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                       // appendStatus("Added service discovery request");
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                        appendStatus("Failed adding service discovery request");
                    }
                });
        manager.discoverServices(channel, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                //appendStatus("Service discovery initiated");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                appendStatus("Service discovery failed");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void connectP2p(WiFiP2pService service) {
        WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
        config.deviceAddress = service.device.deviceAddress;
        config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
        if (serviceRequest != null)
            manager.removeServiceRequest(channel, serviceRequest,
                    new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int arg0) {
                        }
                    });
        manager.connect(channel, config, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                appendStatus("Connecting to service");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int errorCode) {
                appendStatus("Failed connecting to service");
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                Log.d(TAG, readMessage);
                (chatFragment).pushMessage("Friend :" + readMessage);
                break;
            case MY_HANDLE:
                Object obj = msg.obj;
                (chatFragment).setChatManager((ChatManager) obj);
        }
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        receiver = new HomeActivity(manager, channel, this);
        registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo p2pInfo) {
        Thread handler = null;

        if (p2pInfo.isGroupOwner) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected as group owner");
            try {
                handler = new GroupOwnerSocketHandler(
                        ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler());
                handler.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG,
                        "Failed to create a server thread - " + e.getMessage());
                return;
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connected as peer");
            handler = new ClientSocketHandler(
                    ((MessageTarget) this).getHandler(),
                    p2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress);
            handler.start();
        }
        chatFragment = new WiFiChatFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container_root, chatFragment).commit();
        statusTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    public void appendStatus(String status) {
        String current = statusTxtView.getText().toString();
        statusTxtView.setText(current + "\n" + status);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                break;
            case R.id.clean:



                Toast.makeText(this, "Clear Chat", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

And another class which has the `ListView` called `WiFiChatFragment`:

```
public class WiFiChatFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;
    private ChatManager chatManager;
    private TextView chatLine;
    private ListView listView;
    ChatMessageAdapter adapter = null;
    private List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chat, container, false);
        chatLine = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtChatLine);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.id.text1,
                items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        view.findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        if (chatManager != null) {
                            chatManager.write(chatLine.getText().toString()
                                    .getBytes());
                            pushMessage("Me: " + chatLine.getText().toString());
                            chatLine.setText("");
                            chatLine.clearFocus();

                        }
                    }
                });
        return view;



    }
    public interface MessageTarget {
        public Handler getHandler();
    }
    public void setChatManager(ChatManager obj) {
        chatManager = obj;
    }
    public void pushMessage(String readMessage) {
        adapter.add(readMessage);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    /**
     * ArrayAdapter to manage chat messages.
     */
    public class ChatMessageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        List<String> messages = null;
        public ChatMessageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                                  List<String> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);

        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
            }
            String message = items.get(position);

            if (message != null && !message.isEmpty()) {
                TextView nameText = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                if (nameText != null) {
                    nameText.setText(message);
                    if (message.startsWith("Me: ")) {
                        nameText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_b );
                        nameText.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),
                                R.style.normalText);
                    } else {
                        nameText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_a );
                        nameText.setTextAppearance(getActivity(),
                                R.style.boldText);
                    }
                }
            }
            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Adesh you could do this when the overflow item is clicked:

Call setListAdapter() again. This time with an empty ArrayList.

Hope it helps !

Comment: but i want to set for my overflow item click from main activity so how can ?

Comment: You should override your overflow options in your fragment and handle the list clearing there with the set list adapter() to empty list. Check out this SO for a good reference on adding an overflow menu in fragment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714322/how-to-add-action-bar-options-menu-in-android-fragments. Glad to help please remember to mark as answer if it helps ! :)

Comment: @Adeshdhane awesome ! mark as answer if it solves your problem plz !

Comment: but don't know how to do

Comment: There should be a check mark next to the answer so whenever you have a question and you find an answer or the best answer if there are multiple you will want to click the arrow. This allows everyone to feel good about spending the time to answer questions. You can also upvote by hitting the up arrow on the question.